# Print value in console (po) of a instance variable autoreleased

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a variable declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *aInfo;
```

At the beggining, if I declare the variable like this:

```
self.aInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In every point of the app, I can stop the execution with a break point and print the variable content like this:

```
po self.aInfo
```

BUT, if I declared the variable with autorelease (as it should be), I cannot see the content anymore in my breakpoint...

```
self.aInfo = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

PD: If I do something like NSLog(@"%@", self.aInfo) I can see the content...

Comment: what about `po _aInfo` or `po [self aInfo]` - do they still work? (I've assumed that you've synthesised your property as `@synthesize aInfo = _aInfo;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I declared the variable with autorelease (as it should be)...

As it *shouldn't* be. Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *aNewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.aInfo = aNewArray;
[aNewArray release];
```

Or use a convenience method, which is in the autorelease pool and which you do not own, so it can be assigned directly:

```
self.aInfo = [NSMutableArray array];
```

or:

```
self.aInfo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20]; // use whatever number makes sense
```

Remember that when you set up your property to "retain," it does just that. Its synthesized accessors will release the old assignment and retain the new one. So if you assign an alloc'd instance to it directly, that instance will be retained twice, creating a memory leak.*

*Edit: See deanWombourne's comments below. `alloc] init] autorelease` as a direct assignment to a retained property will *not* create a memory leak. But I remain unconvinced that it is memory-efficient.

Comment: I always thought doing this: self.aInfo = [NSMutableArray array]; was the same as doing alloc and autorelease, are not?

Comment: Also, Im doing this: self.aInfo = [NSMutableArray array]; and I have the same result, sorry

Comment: I doublechecked by searching "alloc] init] autorelease" on SO. Adding an instance to the autorelease pool does not immediately lower its retain count; it just ensures that it will be reduced by 1 when the pool is drained. This would be OK if you weren't assigning the instance to a property that actively retains its variables. (As to the "po" question, sorry, I can only guess that it seems to have something to do with the scope of the property; if you assigned the property to a local ivar, "po" would probably work on that ivar -- which doesn't help, I know.)

Comment: Ok, but for example, if Im declaring a UITableView, there's no way of doign something like... [UITableView tableWithFrame... or something like that, I have to alloc it...

Comment: Right, but if a retaining property is populated via the alloc separately/assign/release routine, "po" will work. It's only when you use the autorelease convenience methods that "po" will stumble.

Comment: `alloc] init] autorelease]` is fine if your property is declared as `retain`. It's just as fine as `array]` or `arrayWithCapacity:20]`. and it's just as fine as this answer's `alloc] init];` and then `release]` later. None of these will create a memory leak. Declaring a UITableView will `alloc] init] autorelease]` is fine.

Comment: @deanWombourne, well, I suppose if you release the property upon dealloc, you can prevent that extra retain from keeping the instance around forever -- so you're right; it won't create a true leak. But the instance *will* hang around until the autorelease pool is drained, taking up memory that otherwise would have been freed upon dealloc. Why do that? If there are no convenience methods and you must take ownership, why not take advantage of the efficiency it affords you?

Comment: In what possible case would you _not_ `release` a `retained` property in dealloc? And the autorelease pool will almost certainly have drained way before your dealloc gets called. And do you know how many objects get put into the autorelease pool - it's designed to be pretty efficient! I've never had a scenario where objects living in the autorelease pool caused a problem (excepting cases in tight loops where a second autorelease pool is needed!)

Comment: @deanWombourne: I always assumed there was only *one* pool unless you specifically created nested pools. If so, wouldn't that one pool have to remain undrained until all its objects were no longer in use? And isn't it likely that there will be objects from multiple classes in that pool, making it impossible to drain until *all* those class instances are dealloc'd?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes there's usually only one pool. However, it is emptied very regularly :) All it does when it's drained is pass a `release` message it all the objects currently inside it. If another class has `retain`ed that object then the object stays in memory but the pool doesn't care, it's done it's job!

Comment: @deanWombourne: Gads, I hate to take up your time with this, but I still don’t understand how the pool could work that way. If it drains when some of its objects are still in use (now I’m talking about objects which are not specifically retained elsewhere, whose memory is managed *only* by the pool), then they would be released and you’d crash upon attempting to access them. I guess the regular emptying you’re referring to is different from draining — somehow the pool knows which objects are no longer in use and releases only those?

Comment: @Wienke The overview section of the [NSAutoreleasePool Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)sums it up pretty well.   A pool is created at at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains at the end.  When drained, every object in the pool is sent 'release'.  Any object that wasn't retained elsewhere will be deallocated.  Any object that was retained elsewhere won't be.  It's really that simple.

Comment: I think the confusion might be realising that sending an object a `release` doesn't mean the object will go away - it just means that you're not interested in it any more. Until everyone who has retained it send release, it will stay in memory.